# Why after executing a program would this PowerShell script exit without continuing?

Tags: powershell, mercurial

My `$ErrorActionPreference` is set to `Stop`.

However, there is a fragment of PowerShell (which I have written below), that writes "C" but not "D". Why is the script terminating at the thg line?

```
    Write-Host "C"
    Write-Host "Committing to $path..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
    &thg commit --nofork -R "$path" 2>$null
    Write-Host "D"
```

Comment: In Widows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) versions before 7.2, if you have a `2>` redirection _and_ the external program produces actual stderr output, that stderr output is unexpectedly routed _through PowerShell's error stream_, which - with `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` in effect - causes a script-terminating (fatal) error. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: I've tried setting $EAP to "continue silently" and also removing the 2> redirection, and it still seems to do the same thing. That is, it executes THG but then the script stops before writing D.

Comment: So `thg` produces the expected output, but then the script stops without any error message? Which PowerShell version and host (console window, ISE, ...) are you using?